# Kubernetes duplicate pod kube-system/metrics-server received error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vagrant, hypervisor

I'm currently running a Kubernetes cluster on Vagrant and currently testing the HPA using the [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) but my setup can't seem to read the metrics at all.

My setup consists of a single loadbalancer(HAProxy), a single Master Node, and two worker nodes.

So, I've pulled the log from the metrics-server pod using the following command:

```sh
kubectl logs -n kube-system metrics-server-85cc4d4cb9-sf8wh
```

and it shows the followings:

```sh
E0122 01:53:26.647172       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/metrics-server-85cc4d4cb9-sf8wh received
E0122 01:54:26.653698       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/metrics-server-85cc4d4cb9-sf8wh received
E0122 01:54:26.653838       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/kube-proxy-dk9v8 received
E0122 01:54:26.653864       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/weave-net-jkrn8 received
E0122 01:55:26.647113       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/kube-proxy-dk9v8 received
E0122 01:55:26.647129       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/weave-net-jkrn8 received
E0122 01:55:26.647133       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/metrics-server-85cc4d4cb9-sf8wh received
E0122 01:56:26.646230       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/weave-net-jkrn8 received
E0122 01:56:26.646245       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/metrics-server-85cc4d4cb9-sf8wh received
E0122 01:56:26.646249       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/kube-proxy-dk9v8 received
E0122 01:57:26.691044       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/kube-proxy-dk9v8 received
E0122 01:57:26.691064       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/metrics-server-85cc4d4cb9-sf8wh received
E0122 01:57:26.691069       1 sinkprov.go:135] duplicate pod kube-system/weave-net-jkrn8 received
```

I've tried to search for a similar posts on stackoverflow and github, but couldn't find any.

I hope you guys can help me figure this out.

p.s.

I've done the metrics-server argument setup as well adding `--kubelet-insecure-tls` and more. I'm beginning to think that this is a Hypervisor network issue, or maybe not... I'm too much of a noob to know this at the moment :(

---

I'm starting to think that this was a CNI plugin problem. I've switched from using weavenet CNI plugin to a calico plugin and problem just went away :/... If any one of you can explain this symptom in a much detailed manner I'd really appreciate it! :)

Comment: What is the version of metrics server?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I'm running the latest 0.3.x on the metrics-server on kubernetes version 1.17 :)

Comment: when you do get pods, do you actually see duplicate pods?

Comment: Can you list your system pods? What kind of other `arg` have you used beside the `tls` ?

Comment: @suren nope there weren't any duplicate pods :'(

@acid_fuji I've set `--kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP` as well as `hostNetwork: true`

Comment: I deployed the same environment and metrics server works fine for me on Ubuntu.  Can you please update question with you vagrant file? How are bootstrapping cluster? Using kubeadm?

Answer (score -1):

Your errors seems to be similar to the one mentioned here- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/179

Reason mentioned is - If you are using HPA, and if you have just set the resources in your HPA and you don't set the limits it will behave like this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I've read that through, but I have set the limits on mine. I'm following [this tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) step-by-step, so I don't think the limit is the issue here :'(